# Edit location caret in textbox when form startup c#

Tags: c#, textbox, caret

Why my Caret is display in textbox "Password" when form startup, it is not in textbox "Username Facebook"

Image here:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: You should fix up `TabIndex` on your controls.

Comment: use autofocus="" in username textbox

Answer (score 0):

Make the `TabIndex` of the `Username Facebook` `TextBox` to `0`. This will fix the problem and the cursor will be shown in the `Username Facebook TextBox`